# how to handle duplicate zipped files

Tags: c#, file, duplicates, zip

I have an interesting deli ma on my hands. I have created a program that takes 1-∞ zipped files that also contain X amount of individual files. The files in  different folders sometimes get the same file name for whatever reason. This is my code that I have so far...

What this piece of code does is that after the object that is instantiated another object calls this function called *unzip()*. what all *failsafe.check_directory()* just makes sure that the temporary folder were all the going to be unzipped files are going to go in is empty. the first try catch is for anything I do not know about yet, but the second try catch is for catching duplicate duplicate files so when it actually does happen... the program will not break. So the question I am Asking is what is the best way to handle this exception without just kicking the duplicate to the side or in other words, is there to rename that file before its to late.

```
        public bool unzip()
    {
        int bad_file = 0;
        failsafe.check_directory();
        string dupes = "dupe files\r\n";
       try
         {
            for (int i = 0; i < zippedfolders.Length; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    bad_file = i;
                    ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zippedfolders[i], temppath);
                }
                catch
                {
                    dupes += zippedfolders[bad_file]+"\r\n";
                   continue;
                }

            }
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\MDSSCRUBBER\BUGGED_FILE.txt", dupes);
            files = Directory.GetFiles(temppath);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Instead of using exception for duplicates, why not check the [entries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.entries.aspx) first, and if one of them already [exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx), either skip or [rename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485719.aspx) it. Your current approach would skip an archive even if only one of the file failed.

Comment: That is a good Idea, Ill put up how I tackled this problem in a few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handled it... For some odd reason the Directory class is not creating a folder in the Desktop.

```
 private void fix_desktop()
    {
        string pathington = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop + @"\MrEncrypto\";
        bool check = !Directory.Exists(pathington);
        string finaloutput = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop + @"\MrEncrypto\";
        if (!check)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pathington);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop + @"\MrEncrypto"))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                FileStream fsencrypt = new FileStream(finaloutput + Path.GetFileName(file), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                /** DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                 DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
                 DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);**/
                AesCryptoServiceProvider DES = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
                DES.BlockSize = 128;
                DES.KeySize = 256;
                DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(IV);
                DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
                DES.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                DES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
                CryptoStream ocstream = new CryptoStream(fsencrypt, desencrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                //reading time
                byte[] filetobyte = new byte[fsInput.Length - 1];
                fsInput.Read(filetobyte, 0, filetobyte.Length);
                ocstream.Write(filetobyte, 0, filetobyte.Length);
                fsInput.Close();
                ocstream.Close();
                fsencrypt.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                continue;
            }
        }//foreach
        SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        Encrypto.Enabled = false;
    }//function
```